# php file upload time created

Tags: php

I know that there is a way to get a list of file names in a folder using PHP...

but...

Is there currently any way to get the date/time the file was uploaded/created using php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unix does not keep track of when a file was created, only when it was changed, modified, and accessed.  You can use [filectime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php), [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), and [fileatime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php), respectively to do this.  If you are dealing with uploaded files, it is probably incredibly rare that you would alter the file at any time, so `filemtime()` is likely to give you the creation time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**filemtime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function to get the last modification time of a file and [**fileatime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php) to get the access time.

Answer (score 2):

**filemtime** returns the time when the data blocks of a file were being written to, that is, the time when the content of the file was changed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php

Have a look at the examples. They show the modified time and the accessed time.
Otherwise you could store information in a database and read it from there - but that is much more performance eating.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's stat() function to check:

```
$pathToFile = $_FILE....;

$stat = stat( pathToFile );

echo 'Creation time ' . $stat['mtime'];
```

mtime returns information like [filemtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), but some more details.