# Getting files from folder which uploaded in last 24 hours

Tags: php, file-upload, file-exists

How can i get images (from x directory) which uploaded in last 24 hour?

for example, there are 100 images in **/images/** folder; but 10 of them have been uploaded in last 24 hours. i want to list them via upload time from new to old..

how can i list them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob wrapper to list files in directory X ([PHP manual glob wrapper](http://php.net/manual/it/wrappers.glob.php)).
Use filemtime to get file modification time.

Answer (score 0):

[filectime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php), from PHP docs:

> Returns the time the file was last changed, or FALSE on failure. The time is returned as a Unix timestamp.

You can check if the timestamp returned by filectime(), is bigger than timestamp of a day back.

try this:

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/dir/';
$yesterday = strtotime("-1 day");
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (filectime($path.$entry) > $yesterday) {
            echo filectime($path.$entry) . ":" . $entry . " "."\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

code above will echo only files created in the past day.

Comment: last update time and last upload/last create times looks different; i need to sort via upload time.. cant i use anything instead of filectime() or filemtime() to list files by upload time?

Comment: @user3283814 I believe those are your best bet. Look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5849725/2460773 let me know if it answeres your question.

Comment: This will do the job recursively: <?php shell_exec('find /directory_path -mtime -1 -ls');

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you make a column of Serial number on your Database. then you have to select maximum serial number as...

```
 <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","phpuser","phppass");
$db="databasename";
mysql_select_db($db);

$qd=mysql_query("select max(srl_num) from tablename");
$lf=mysql_fetch_row($qd);
$lf1=$lf[0];

$qd=mysql_query("select * from  tablename where srl_num= '$lf1' ");
$qd1=mysql_fetch_row($qd);

$lfn=$qd1[0];

$fn=$qd1[2];
$fn2=$qd1[3];
?>
```

and echo $fn and fn2 as your wish